# Unreachable Code - Placing a break after a return in switch statement

Tags: java, netbeans, methods

I've tried looking this up, and although other people have asked this, their situation applies to different things (as far as I can tell).

I am learning Java, and I am creating a program that "talks" with the user, asking questions and stuff. As a step to actually learning the concepts of object-oriented programming, I created a class that helps my main project NOT be filled with the handling of questions, instead I put the handling and returns for most questions in a class called ConversationHelper.

I created a method in my ConversationHelper for asking Yes/No questions. Here is its code:

```
public boolean askYNQuestion(String question) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean isInputCorrect = false;

    while(isInputCorrect == false) {
    displayQuestion(question + " (Y or N)");
    String readin = input.nextLine();

    switch (readin.toLowerCase()) {
        case "n":
            return false;
            break;
        case "y":
            return true;
            break;
        case "yes":
            return true;
            break;
        case "no":
            return false;
            break;
        case "false":
            return false;
            break;
        case "true":
            return true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
    System.out.println("THIS IS NOT SUPPOSED TO HAPPEN! FALSE DEFAULT!");
    return false;
}
```

The problem with this is more of an annoyance than anything else. Every break in the switch statement comes up with "unreachable code" because there is a return statement before it. However, this is meant to happen.

Netbeans now tells me, at build, that the "compiler ran with errors." Not only is this just annoying, but it makes it hard to tell if the error is this known error, or if it is another error that needs my attention, wasting time when I'm trying to make my program work.

I'm looking for either a better way to do this that won't generate errors, or a way to force disable this error from coming up. I am running Netbeans, with Java 8. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: As well, I have verified that the program can still run. It isn't preventing me from running it, but it is creating annoyances and making it harder to debug.

Comment: Why must you keep a `break` after a `return`? I can't think of any reason you would need this and by removing them you would solve your problem. Also, you could simplify your code by taking advantage of the fact that switch statements "fall through" (I think that is the term)

Comment: @Takendarkk Return statements return, if that case is triggered. Do return statements automatically act as break statements? If not, I still need them to keep the switch statement functional (since the compiler looks for that to end the case and move on to the next).

Comment: A return will act as a break. In terms of my "falling through" statement try something like `case "n": case "no": case "false": return false;`

Comment: It is not valid Java to have anything after the return including break. though Netbeans will run it, it will not compile under normal circumstances.

Comment: @Takendarkk Ah, thank you! You should post that as an answer so other people can see it if they need to.

Comment: In general, the default warnings on a widely used IDE such as Netbeans are appropriate unless/until you are doing something very advanced or maintaining existing code with problems. When writing new code, aim to make it compile without errors or warnings, rather than shooting the messenger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `return` will act as a `break`. There is no need to use both. If you receive the message that you have unreachable code, then there is either no point in it being there, or something you did previously is out of order logically.

As a second point, just to improve your code, you can combine conditions in your switch statement. If you have multiple items which will return the same thing, you can list them one after the other and put a single return for them all.

```
 switch (readin.toLowerCase()) {
    case "n":
    case "no":
    case "false":
        return false;
    case "y":
    case "yes":
    case "true":
        return true;
    default:
        break;
}
```