# Does a "return..." statement make a "break;" moot?

Tags: objective-c, return, switch-statement

I came to Objective-C from a VB.NET background where the `switch` statement is `Select Case` and no `break` statements are needed (or possible).

I know that the general rule is to place a `break` statement at the end of each `case` statement so that execution doesn't "fall through" to the next `case` statement.

When writing iOS apps, I frequently have `switch` statements in my `-tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:` methods. Basically, I often let my cells report the height needed, so I end up with `switch` statements like this:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        return ...
        break;
    case 1:
        return ...
        break;

    ...

    default:
        return ...
        break;
}
```

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048769/unreachable-code-placing-a-break-after-a-return-in-switch-statement), which makes sense to me and is what I expect the answer to be, but that question is specifically about Java, and I wanted to see if the same answer holds true for Objective-C.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957038/break-in-a-case-with-return-and-for-default), which relates to C, which I assume is the correct answer for Objective-C, as well.

So, is a `return` statement a specialized `break` statement?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No a return statement is not a specialised break. return causes you to exit the function break causes you to exit the switch statement. You don't need the break if you have the return, but they are different things.

Comment: I get your point, but it seems to me that it **is** a specialized break in that it does everything a break does, and then some. My main question is about the "does everything a break does", so I don't want to quibble about the semantics of the "and then some". Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic behind the scene. The only big difference here is that with break you only leave the switch with return the function. So the consequences are obvious. If you have return you do not need a break as the break will never be reached. Some IDE will it grey out to point you out it is not reachable fragment of code.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your ideas about `switch` and `return`, yes, a `return` statement can be considered as a specialized `break` statement.

[A `break` is just a branch table abstraction, so as `return` is](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162574/why-do-we-have-to-use-break-in-switch), so at the end of the day, they will simply execute a jump instruction.